# Invalid date format error yyyymmddhhmmss in c#

Tags: c#, c#-3.0

My requirement was to write a code that can accept two type of date format i.e yyyymmddhhmmss  and yyyymmdd.
I have written the code but it is working for few date but not for all.

```
string[] formats = { "yyyymmdd","yyyymmddhhmmss" };

if (!DateTime.TryParseExact(DesiredReportVersionDate, formats, new CultureInfo("en-US"), DateTimeStyles.None, out timevalue))
        {

            valid = false;
            throw new Exception("invalid format" + timevalue);
        }
```

However,passing 19901212033047 value is giving exception.It should be valid as per my understanding.

Please help.

Thanks in advance

Comment: http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/Article/23/Date-Formatting-in-CSharp Care about those M and m ('s)

Comment: Or indeed MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx Always read the documentation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use this `yyyyMMddHHmmss`. Because it's case sensitive

Comment: Thanks a lot Sir,I was not considering that case sensitive issue.

Answer (score 0):

Capital letters matter. In your case use capital `MM` instead of `mm`.